# How to apply macro to all rows?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code, and it works for the first value in the column, but I need the code to be modified so that it applies the if statement to all the values in the column. Right now it is putting the result as 40 + for all the values in column K, but I need the code to run so that it first evaluates K2, then K3, then K4 etc. Please help!

```
Sub UPTRange()



Dim UPT As Range, cell As Range, result As Range
Set UPT = Range("K2:K2642")
Set result = Range("L2:L2642")

For Each cell In UPT

If cell.Value >= 40 Then
result = "40 +"
ElseIf cell.Value = (30 <= 39) Then
result = "30 - 39"
ElseIf cell.Value = (20 <= 29) Then
result = "20 - 29"
ElseIf cell.Value = (10 <= 19) Then
result = "10 - 19"
ElseIf cell.Value = (2 <= 9) Then
result = "2 - 9"
ElseIf cell.Value = (0 <= 1) Then
result = "0 - 1"
Else: cell.Value = "Error"
End If

Next

For Each cell In result

Range("L2").Value = result
Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

```
If cell.Value = (30 <= 39) Then
```

is the same as

```
If cell.Value = True Then
```

Because you're evaluating the expression `30 <= 39`, which gives `True`...

If you want to check for a range then you should use something like

```
If cell.Value > 30 And cell.Value <= 39 Then
```

Once you have a value in `result` then just do this:

```
cell.offset(0, 1).Value = result
```

to place `result` one cell to the right of `cell`

**EDIT**

```
Sub UPTRange()

    Dim UPT As Range, cell As Range, result, v

    Set UPT = ActiveSheet.Range("K2:K2642")

    For Each cell In UPT

    v=cell.value

    If v >= 40 Then
        result = "40 +"
    ElseIf v > 30 And v <= 39) Then
        result = "30 - 39"
    ElseIf
        'etc etc
    Else
        result = "Error"
    End If

    cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = result

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi. thanks for the feedback, but I do not see that is really solves the issue. I am able to get a result into the cell I need, but the formula does not seem to cycle through all the cells in column k. do you know a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this??

```
If cell.Value >= 40 Then
    cell.Formula = "40 +"
ElseIf cell.Value >= 10 And cell.Value < 40 Then
    cell.Formula = (Int(cell.Value / 10) * 10) & " - " & (Int(cell.Value / 10) * 10) + 9
ElseIf cell.Value > 1 And cell.Value < 10 Then
    cell.Formula = "2 - 9"
Else
    cell.Formula = "Error"
End If
```